# How can I realize pattern promise/defered?

Tags: c#, promise

I want to write a pattern Promise/Deffered.
Perfect variant in end is:

```
MyObject().CallMethodReturningPromise()
   .done( result => {
       ...something doing;
   } )
   .fail( error => {
       ...error handle;
   } )
   .always( () => {
       ...some code;
   } )
```

I've found this implementation https://bitbucket.org/mattkotsenas/c-promises/overview and https://gist.github.com/cuppster/3612000. But how can I use it to solve my task???

Comment: Out of interest, is there a practical difference between the Futures pattern and Promises?

Comment: @Gusdor the terminology is blurry - these terms mean different things in different languages.

Comment: As a side note promises are _not_ about `.done` `.fail` and `.always` - they're more about `.then` and `.catch` for error handling. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I was under the impression that `Future` was a universal term. Imagine my disappointment when c# called them Tasks.

Comment: If you can't use Task (because you are stuck in an older version of .Net) I have a C# promise implementation that you might like to try. https://github.com/Real-Serious-Games/C-Sharp-Promise.  Also available on nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RSG.Promise/

Comment: @AshleyDavis Your promise library looks great. Does it also work with `async` and `await` natively? i.e. for operations that don't have a completed or done event, unlike `DownloadStringCompleted` for `WebClient`.

Comment: Unfortunately we only use .Net 3.5, so I don't yet have any experience with async/await. Please jump into the github project and try it out, if it doesn't do what you want then we can work that out together.

Comment: @AshleyDavis Had a play with your library over the weekend, love it! Submitted a pull request with async/await example usage.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### C# solves this with `Task`s

Tasks solve the same problem as promises do in JavaScript - and you can use them similarly. However normally, you shouldn't.

There are several differences:

- Tasks have cancellation built in.
- Tasks aren't always started, and you can have tasks and start them later.
- Promises perform assimilation, you can't have a `Promise<Promise<T>>` but you can have a task of a task in C# and might need to call `.Unwrap` on tasks.
- There is one canonical implementation of tasks in the TPL (task parallelization library) that ships with C# but many implementations of promises in JavaScript.

### Using Tasks

Here's how you'd use them with the `async/await` syntax - which will be added to JavaScript in ES7 and can be used in ES6 with `yield` in some libraries.

```
async Task Foo(){
    try{
        var res = await myObject.CallMethodReturningTaskOrAsyncMethod();
        doSomethingWithResponse(res);
    } catch(e){
         // handle errors, this will be called if the async task errors
    } finally {
        // this is your .always
    }
}
```

You can also [use `.ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288(v=vs.110).aspx) which parallels to `.then` but it's very uncommon in C# and is generally frowned upon when await can be used. You can learn more about [using `async`/`await` here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Deffereds are mapped to `TaskCompletionSource` instances and `Promise`s are `Task`s in C#. `Task.WhenAll` is used where you'd use `$.when` or `Promise.all`.

Where you'd usually write:

```
a().then(function(res){
    return b(res, "foo");
}).then(function(res2){
    // do work on res2
});
```

You'd do the following in C#:

```
var res = await a();
var res2 = await b(res, "foo");
// do work on res2.
```

Comment: @Multix with try/catch, in async functions in C#, you can use regular try/catch and handle asynchronous errors. Using `async/await` is useful for letting you write asynchronous code in a synchronous way. It's a _really_ powerful abstraction and you'll really enjoy it coming from JavaScript.

Comment: The [try/catch reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) contains examples using async as well as a short tutorial on how they recommend handling errors with it and best practices.

Comment: @Multix any progress? Did you end up solving it with my answer?

Comment: @ImBlueDaBaDee *Why* did you propose your edit? The edit comment should cover that.

Answer (score 28):

Seems to me, this perfectly fit with [tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var deferred = Task
    .Factory
    .StartNew(() => /* produce some result (promise) */);

// done
deferred
    .ContinueWith(d => Console.WriteLine(d.Result), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

// fail
deferred
    .ContinueWith(d => Console.WriteLine(d.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

// always
deferred
    .ContinueWith(d => Console.WriteLine("Do something"));
```

Comment: is there a way to ensure that the continuation gets called on the same thread ?

Comment: @zumalifeguard: look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14058118/580053. In short, you can't ensure this in general. Maybe you're trying to do something wrong - it is better to describe particular problem you want to solve this way.

Comment: I need to run on the same thread because I want to access a resources from the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

you can use asynchronous with *Task*, *async* and *await* as follows:
**pay attention for handling asynchronous you do not need use try catch**

```
 public async Task Method()
   {
     await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //operations
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    //grab the UI Dispatcher if you need
                });
            }).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsCompleted)
                {
                    //operations success
                }
                else if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    //operations failed
                }
            });
        }
```