# Using Task.Factory.StartNew with Thread.Sleep to wait x seconds

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Can I do something like that in order to wait, for example 5 seconds, before continue with other method and without freeze my UI ?

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    // Code to do some method
});
```

Comment: What does "Wait without Freezing" mean?

Comment: I don't want to use Thread.Sleep because it freeze my UI

Comment: How does it freeze your ui? What do you mean exactly by the UI being frozen?

Answer (score 10):

You should use:

```
await Task.Delay(5000);
```

Comment: In fact, IIRC, this is the recommended way of delaying a running task.

Comment: The only difference is that the code after the `Task.Delay()` is executed on the current dispatcher instead of the `Factory.StartNew` `ThreadPool` thread.

Comment: And if OP is not targeting .NET 4.5?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek: He could spawn a thread, `Thread.Sleep()` on it and invoke a delegate on the `Dispatcher` to Continue execution without blocking the UI.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek In that case he should have put the appropriate .Net tag in his question; otherwise, the default is to assume that they are using a version that's not more than a year old. Or he could use [Async for .Net 4](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async)

Comment: @MatthewWatson I was not aware of such a convention here on SO.

Comment: Also a big difference is that the `Task.Delay()` will use a `Timer` instead of blocking a thread for waiting.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek I just meant that people tend to assume you're using the latest stuff unless otherwise stated - otherwise every answer would have to provide solutions for versions of .Net going back years. For example, people will tend to provide answers which require the use of Linq, even though that didn't exist in .Net 2.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yeah, it gives a sense to me :)

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.Sleep()` is not recommended. There is no good in blocking a thread/task for 5 seconds.

As mentioned in [@Jeroen van Langen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19399800/1529246), `await Task.Delay()` is the best way. However, if for some reason you are not able to use `async/await` mechanism, second best option will be to setup a one-time 5 second timer. `Windows.Forms.Timer` for WinForms or `DispatcherTimer` for WPF.

(`Task.Delay()` is in turn implemented by a timer.)

Comment: What about using Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(x => MyMethod()) ?? and what is the meaning of await before Task.Delay() ?

Comment: Sure you can, but be careful, your delegate will not run on UI thread by default. You will have to pass the SynchronizationContextSchedueler to the `ContinueWith` method. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4331287/1529246

Comment: To learn about `await` use your favorite search engine and search for `c# 5.0 async await`. It is new C# 5.0 feature - and it is non-blocking. `await` also captures current synchrinizationcontext automatically.

Comment: This not compile:             Task UITask = Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(() =>
            {
                myMethod();
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); Delegate 'System.Action<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' does not take 0 argumen

Comment: change it to this `...ContinueWith( _ => { myMethod(); } ...` where the `_` represents the completed task of `Task.Delay()`. You generally wont use that variable so convention is to name it `_`.