# append to textbox from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, invoke

I've a Form with many tabs and I want to write to them in the same time from many threads 
(`UI BackGroundWorker` etc.)
I've written this code and it is working on main tab ( the one that is visible when app starts )

```
    public struct Struct_Append
    {
        public RichTextBox Screen;
        public string Message;
        public Color Color;
    }

    public void AppendAllTextAllScreen (Struct_Append append  )
    {
        RichTextBox screenToPrint = append.Screen;
        Font font = new Font("Tahoma", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
        if (screenToPrint.InvokeRequired) //&& this.Visible)
        {

            append.Message = append.Message + "\n";
            try
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action<Struct_Append>(AppendAllTextAllScreen), new object[] { 
                append });
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //handle exception
            }
             return; 
        }
        append.Message = append.Message + "\n";

        screenToPrint.SelectionFont = font;
        screenToPrint.SelectionColor = append.Color;
        screenToPrint.AppendText(append.Message);
    }
```

It is working from any thread , but once I set the screen to some of the other tabs , and fire it

```
        Struct_Append structAppend1 = new Struct_Append();
        structAppend1.Screen = scrnSta1;
        structAppend1.Color = Color.Bisque;
        structAppend1.Message = "THIS IS A TEST";
        AppendAllTextAllScreen(structAppend1);
```

**VisualStudio2013 just get stuck and restart it self!!!!**

**BUT** when I run it without DEBUG it runs fine

**EDIT** code that I used that spawn the ERROR

this is the I used to test the `appendText` method above

```
private async void DoSomthing()
{
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                _Append structAppend1 = new _Append();
                structAppend1.Screen = ScrnSta1; ;
                structAppend1.Color = Color.Bisque;
                structAppend1.Message = "THIS IS A TEST";
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    AppendAllTextAllScreen(structAppend1);
                }


            });
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                _Append structAppend = new _Append();
                structAppend.Color = Color.Aquamarine;
                structAppend.Message = "THIS IS A TEST";
                structAppend.Screen = ScrnSta2;
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    AppendAllTextAllScreen(structAppend);
                }
            });
}
```

scrnsta1/2 are two seperated tabs in my `Form` (main UI thread), and I call this method from there(UI thread)

what am I missing here ?

Comment: Start without debugging and see the result. Maybe VS is buggy

Comment: Why are you using a mutable struct with public fields to start with?

Comment: Were your multiple tabs all started from the same thread? (I'd hope so, but...)

Comment: @JonSkeet this is just for this particular test , It should be written in class , yes all thread are started from the UI thread

Comment: @Georgi-it I've tried it and sadly you'r right , what can I do to fix it ? re-install VS ?

Comment: Try with a different version, 2013 or 2012. If both don't work probably you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Georgi-it I would like to add my code that spawn the error for you to look at , because I dont have the permission to add another VS in that time

Comment: I would recommend to continue the tasks on the UI thread without using invoke. It is much safer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331262/task-continuation-on-ui-thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, access to Windows Forms controls from a different thread must be done by means of the [Invoke method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `Control`, which needs the definition of suitable delegates. In your example, these delegates would be basically the lambda expressions used in the implementation of `DoSometing`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont understand where are you getting with it(maybe the problem is in me ).. Please look above , You'll see my implementation as you mentioned

Comment: You already seem to use the `Invoke` method, however you do not check whether the call to `Invoke` is actually necessary. The Property `InvokeRequired` of Control, documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx can be used to decide whether `Invoke` should be used from the current thread or not.

Comment: I actually use the property as you mentioned 
"if (screenToPrint.InvokeRequired)" or you mean some other kind of implementation ?

Comment: codor you are RIGHT it was my mistake

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to continue the tasks on the UI thread without using invoke. It is much safer and less error prone: [Task continuation on UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331262/task-continuation-on-ui-thread)

```
Task UITask= task.ContinueWith(() =>
{
 this.TextBlock1.Text = "Complete"; 
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: I get this error Error 8 Delegate'System.Action<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' does not take 0 arguments 
what should I put inside the lambda expression ?