# Processing intermittent IO jobs with TPL and/or BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a C# application that interacts with a few serial and USB devices. I am trying to find a nice way to command these devices in a parallel fashion so that many can be controlled at once. I will initiate commands to the device via user input and also scripted commands.

I am currently trying to figure out a clean way to "collect" and run commands in parallel to my UI thread. I have multiple forms, one for each device, each have a few controls that can issue commands.

The way I currently see it a user will click a button which will fire an event in the form. Another class lets call it `CommandManager` will hook into all of these events; each event passes the necessary information to form a command to send to a device.

When the event is handled by the `CommandManager` it forms the command and adds it to a `BlockingCollection<Command>` in a subclassed `BackgroundWorker` named `DeviceCommandWorker` which was started when the application opened. All it does is loop over a block of code containing a `Task.Factory.StartNew()` call.

In the `StartNew` block `Take` is called on the `BlockingCollection` waiting for a command to be input. Once a command is in the collection the `Take` returns and the `Task` goes off on its merry way. The `BackgroundWorker` loops back around and repeats the process until it is cancelled.

```
// Event handler running on the UI Thread
public void ProcessCommand(DeviceCommand command)
{
    // I assume I cannot add to Commands (BlockingCollection) from here?
    DeviceCommandWorker.Instance.Commands.Add(command);
}

// ....
// BackgroundWorker started upon Application startup
// ...

public class DeviceCommandWorker : BackgroundWorker
{
    public static DeviceCommandWorker Instance { get { return lazyInstance.Value; } }
    private static readonly Lazy<DeviceCommandWorker> lazyInstance = new Lazy<DeviceCommandWorker>(() => new DeviceCommandWorker());

    public BlockingCollection<DeviceCommand> Commands { get; set; } 

    private DeviceCommandWorker()
    {
        WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        Commands = new BlockingCollection<DeviceCommand>();
    }

    protected override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (!CancellationPending)
        {
            var commandTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                // If the BackGroundWorker is cancelled, how to esacpe this blocking call?
                DeviceCommand command = commandQueue.Take(); 

                DeviceCommandResult result;
                command.Process(out result);

                if(result == DeviceCommandResult.Error)
                    ; // How would I inform the UI of this result?
            });
        }
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

My questions are stated in the code above but I will reiterate them.

My first issue is that I do not think I can add to the `BlockingCollection` from outside the running `BackGroundWorker`? (From reading about the TPL, shouldn't there be a sync object I can lock on when adding?)

Assuming that I can add to the collection, is there no way to escape the `Take` method when it is blocking, specifically if the `BackgroundWorker` was cancelled wouldn't it just be blocked forever? (Possibly before  cancellation I could send a "custom command" that simply creates a task that does nothing, I would then be able to exit the while loop)

Finally, how would I report either success or errors in command execution back to the UI thread? I have seen this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4331287/2985796), is that the right direction to head in?

Comment: Use [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I looked into TPL Dataflow. Restrictions keep me from getting the package in any reasonable time to work with. But when I do get it I will try to rework a solution in that manner and determine which I like more. // Could you comment on the above solution at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some more tinkering it looks like I got the idea above to work pretty well for me initially. I am not sure how it will perform when it comes time to do some real work but I am happy so far.

So I reworked the code. I found that without the `Take` outside of the `Task.Factory.StartNew()` I was actually just making tasks as fast as possible each waiting to consume from the `BlockingCollection`. So I moved the statement outside of the loop. I also confirmed that to break from the blocking `Take` I will need to send some sort of special command so that I can stop the background worker. Finally (not shown) I plan to use `Control.Invoke` to return any failures to the UI thread.

```
public Boolean StartCommandWorker()
{
    if (DeviceCommandWorker.Instance.IsBusy)
        return false;
    else
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Called start command worker!");
        DeviceCommandWorker.Instance.RunWorkerAsync();
        return DeviceCommandWorker.Instance.IsBusy;
    }
}

public void StopCommandWorker()
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Called stop command worker!");
    ProcessCommand("QUIT");
    DeviceCommandWorker.Instance.CancelAsync();
}

public Boolean ProcessCommand(String command)
{
    DeviceCommandWorker.Instance.Commands.Add(command);
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Enqueued command \"" + command + "\" ThreadID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    return true;
}

internal class DeviceCommandWorker : BackgroundWorker
{
    public static DeviceCommandWorker Instance { get { return lazyInstance.Value; } }
    private static readonly Lazy<DeviceCommandWorker> lazyInstance = new Lazy<DeviceCommandWorker>(() => new DeviceCommandWorker());

    public BlockingCollection<String> Commands { get; set; }

    private DeviceCommandWorker()
    {
        WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        Commands = new BlockingCollection<String>();
    }

    protected override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Background Worker Started ThreadID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        while (!CancellationPending)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Waiting for command on ThreadID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            String aString = Commands.Take();

            var commandTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("   Dequeued command \"" + aString + "\" ThreadID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                if (aString.Equals("QUIT"))
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("   Quit worker called: " + aString);
            });
        }

        Console.Out.WriteLine("Background Worker: Stopped!");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Here is some sample output. I made a small UI form that I could start, stop, and send commands with. It simply sends a random double as a command.

```
Called start command worker!
Background Worker Started ThreadID: 17
Waiting for command on ThreadID: 17
Enqueued command "Hello" ThreadID: 10
Waiting for command on ThreadID: 17
   Dequeued command "Hello" ThreadID: 16
Enqueued command "0.0745" ThreadID: 10
Waiting for command on ThreadID: 17
   Dequeued command "0.0745" ThreadID: 12
Enqueued command "0.7043" ThreadID: 10
   Dequeued command "0.7043" ThreadID: 16
Waiting for command on ThreadID: 17
Called stop command worker!
Enqueued command "QUIT" ThreadID: 10
   Dequeued command "QUIT" ThreadID: 12
   Quit worker called: QUIT
Background Worker: Stopped!
Enqueued command "0.2646" ThreadID: 10
Enqueued command "0.1619" ThreadID: 10
Enqueued command "0.5570" ThreadID: 10
Enqueued command "0.4129" ThreadID: 10
Called start command worker!
Background Worker Started ThreadID: 12
Waiting for command on ThreadID: 12
Waiting for command on ThreadID: 12
Waiting for command on ThreadID: 12
Waiting for command on ThreadID: 12
Waiting for command on ThreadID: 12
   Dequeued command "0.2646" ThreadID: 16
   Dequeued command "0.1619" ThreadID: 16
   Dequeued command "0.5570" ThreadID: 16
   Dequeued command "0.4129" ThreadID: 16
Enqueued command "0.8368" ThreadID: 10
   Dequeued command "0.8368" ThreadID: 17
Waiting for command on ThreadID: 12
Called stop command worker!
Enqueued command "QUIT" ThreadID: 10
   Dequeued command "QUIT" ThreadID: 16
   Quit worker called: QUIT
Background Worker: Stopped!
```