# Task.ContinueWith() is not working after the Task.Run()

Tags: c#, xamarin

Im doing with the activity indicator of the xamarin.
I want to stop the indicator after the product is get.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (!_appeared) // Avoid repeat loding
        {
            activity.IsEnabled = true;
            activity.IsRunning = true;
            activity.IsVisible = true;

            var task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                ProductViewData productViewData = new ProductViewData();
                products = productViewData.GetProductList("10");
                count = 10;
                productListView.ItemsSource = products;
            });

            task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                activity.IsEnabled = false;
                activity.IsRunning = false;
                activity.IsVisible = false;
            });

            _appeared = true;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331262/task-continuation-on-ui-thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code like this is a lot easier with async/await:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    if (!_appeared) // Avoid repeat loding
    {
        _appeared = true;
        activity.IsEnabled = true;
        activity.IsRunning = true;
        activity.IsVisible = true;

        var products = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ProductViewData productViewData = new ProductViewData();
            return productViewData.GetProductList("10");
        });

        productListView.ItemsSource = products;

        activity.IsEnabled = false;
        activity.IsRunning = false;
        activity.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

Although the code is simple and readable, there's a lot going on behind the scenes, particularly around when this method returns, and what thread the code after the `await` is run on. It is well worth reading up on this.

Comment: this throw me an error and i dont know what is it.
`Unhandled Exception:
Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. occurred`

Comment: @Jweiwei ah, you need to move `productListView.ItemsSource = products` out of the `Task.Run`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: done. but how it work actually? not really understand await and async =(

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you need.

```
var task = Task.Run(delegate { Console.WriteLine("Task started!"); })
           .ContinueWith(delegate { Console.WriteLine("Task continued"); });
```

Just wrap what you wanna do as functions and call that functions in your task steps. For more information read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=xamarinios-10.8).

**Edit:**

Since an UI operation is the subject of this question, I thought this code from the page I linked would be more useful. This code utilizes UI and background scheduler.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
   var backgroundScheduler = TaskScheduler.Default;  
   var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();  
   Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate { DoBackgroundComputation(); },  
                         backgroundScheduler).  
   ContinueWith(delegate { UpdateUI(); }, uiScheduler).  
                ContinueWith(delegate { DoAnotherBackgroundComputation(); },  
                             backgroundScheduler).  
                ContinueWith(delegate { UpdateUIAgain(); }, uiScheduler);  
}
```

Comment: This won't work, as the continuation won't be run on the UI thread

Comment: Your code does not even compile! Stop editing things before trying. @canton7

Comment: My bad, `.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("..."))` would be correct. Nobody uses the anonymous delegate syntax since C# 3 introduced lambdas, though.

Comment: No, it would not work as well. Also, editing answers to the question that you also answered does not look ethical. More improtantly, as you can see in the page I linked, microsoft's itself publish code with delegate. I do not think nobody uses them anymore.@canton7

Comment: Yes, it would do the same thing. SO is a Q/A site, and having a range of different high-quality answers is good. I'm not trying to get my answer to "win", I'm trying to improve the site by getting a range of good-quality answers. That includes improving other answers. If your answer took account of dispatching back to the UI thread (e.g. using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`), I would upvote it as well. I don't see anything unethical about this approach to improving overall quality. Also, the MSDN examples are often of low quality.

Comment: It does not look like you are not trying to 'win' when editing my code with some garbage. Also, in the page I linked there are examples and first of them utilizes TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()). I just added a basic code so do not  just read the code snippets before judging. @canton7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188515/discussion-between-canton7-and-hasan).